# Calculating height using jQuery differs in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, height, css

I have a question that was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518436/jquery-height-problem-with-chrome), but the solution offered there did not work. The problem is that I'm using the jQuery height() function to return the height of a div. It works nicely in Firefox, but returns a value that is 300px smaller in Chrome...

You can see an example of this bug [here](http://engineercreativity.com/samples/sheli). Though I must say it's in Hebrew. Though that shouldn't matter much...

Has anyone had that happen before? Here's the code that calculates the height:

```
var heightLeftCol = $('#leftCol').height();
var sidebarHeight = $('#sidebar').height();
var minHeight = heightLeftCol > sidebarHeight ? heightLeftCol : sidebarHeight; 
$('#postArea').css('min-height', minHeight+100);
```

EDIT: This problem was **not fixed** but **worked around** in a way that I don't like, but it'll do for now. Here's the "solution" that I came up with:

```
if (jQuery.browser.safari) {
    $('#postArea').css('min-height', minHeight+400 + 'px');
}
else {
    $('#postArea').css('min-height', minHeight+100 + 'px');
}
```

Since both Safari and Chrome run on WebKit, the `browser.safari` actually selects chrome as well..I definitely do not consider this an optimal solution.

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: An issue that has to do with font height and you are saying that it being in Hebrew should not matter?  Sad to say both of these browsers were originally developed in another language, I would say the font being Hebrew most likely IS the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Hogan: You need to differentiate between content and styling. Styling controls the font of the content. Content just sits there. The font and size of this site is `font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; `. Therefore it doesn't matter what language it's in, that is the properties of the content.

Comment: Also, if I may add. It's pathetic that IE7 and 8 properly render this site while Chrome, which considers itself to be a leading browser, fails to do so.

Comment: @Amit, is the discrepancy still there if you use .outerHeight(true) instead of .height()? I have at times run into issues where I've had to use the outerHeight of elements to get appropriate results. Documentation on outerHeight can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Comment: The height as calculated by jQuery in different browsers may execute before images are loaded, so any images in your divs could be counted as 0 height at the time the script runs. Specify the height of your images in html or css to include them in the calculation.

Comment: This is a good point @JustinStolle this can be prevented by running this code in $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready() to ensure all images are loaded and are being counted in the heights of divs.

Comment: I can upcote your comment but think the more correct answer is running this code in $(window).load() to avoid needing to set your height explicitly :O but you are right the jQuery community is quck to ask here but stingy with up votes.

Comment: @Jeremy, I have upvoted your comment too because while I've identified the root cause and the solution, you've identified another good solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Chrome, the height of the div does not include the height of your 300-pixel tall image "sheli.jpg" because it isn't specified anywhere in the html or css.  If you specify the `height="300"` in your <img> tag or `height: 300px;` as part its style, it will work.

Comment: giving you the +1 here anyway because I know how hard they are to get for jQuery questions :-)

Answer (score 8):

If is because your image at that time is not yet loaded, therefore the height is 0. That explains the height deficit you got in Chrome. To solve this problem, put the piece of code that set the height inside `jQuery(window).load()` like this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
     jQuery("#div1").css("height", jQuery("#div2").height());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, +1, though the problem was solved using strict HTML markup, by just assigning the HTML img tag the `height` property. This makes for a better cleaner JS file as well as validated HTML code

Comment: @Amit: I guess it would be ok in your case, but if the image is anything other `300px height`, you would either shrink or stretch your image. In my opinion, that is not a good design. Well, take care then

Answer (score 5):

Per the discussion Justin and I had in the comments above wrapping the jQuery code in $(window).load() will allow this code to execute properly after the images have loaded completely.

Comment: This works and is less effort than specifying height values, but it also means that the layout changes made in the script won't happen until after the images load. Under normal circumstances, this will happen quickly enough, but reduced bandwidth or many large resources could be a factor. Just something to consider.

Comment: Certainly this works as well. I wish I could give out two checks.