# Issues with Fixed div on bottom of page that stops at given place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We needed a footer toolbar that stays at the bottom of the page, and sticks to some area when page is scrolled below that area.

We did achieved this using following script:

[fixed div on bottom of page that stops in given place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141425/fixed-div-on-bottom-of-page-that-stops-in-given-place)

But there is an issue on some page where the footer toolbar just disappears from the page, and then appear again when page is scrolled down further.

We found that this particular issue appears only on few page, when the page has some contents like Images, Video, or Ajax load other content where the content is filled in (or space is being filled) after page has loaded.

I have no clue how to fix this.

Here is the link from live site with problem page.

http://www.sandiegopchelp.com/services/cellphone-repair/htc/

http://www.sandiegopchelp.com/top-10-tips-to-help-secure-your-computer/

http://www.sandiegopchelp.com/notes-on-the-phablet-does-the-world-need-one/

It is usually more visible on blog posts with many comments. May be due to Disqus comments being loaded after the page has loaded completely.

Comment: its cant understand well until the code post...

Comment: Here is the link to the exact code: http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/1/

Comment: @krunaloverflow check this http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/200/

Comment: @naimshaikh thank you for your update. Actually that has fixed the div to the bottom. So it stays there all the time. But my requirement is to have fixed div on bottom of page that stops at given place.

Comment: @krunaloverflow sorry for that, I understood now, what actually you are looking for....

Comment: @naimshaikh. Its okay, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried making it two different elements? 1 element is in the flow, and the floating element is shown ONLY when (scrollTop + windowHeight) > inline element position. That way you're basically making two things that function exactly how you want, instead of trying to make one thing function as two things. EDIT: Make sure you don't have duplicate id's if you go this route.

Comment: No we didn't try, but does it make any difference, because we actually have issues with positioning and problem occurs when there is dynamic content is loaded inside, so can't understand what difference it will make?

Comment: Hmmm, i couldnt create you specific failure on the page, but it seems to me like a change to the .load() event instead of .ready() could solve some of your problems. on ready only the dom structure should be available. The described images videos etc. are loaded afterwards. In this case the load event could be helpful, but it causes the action to wait until everything is there... Had similar probs on that effect :(

Answer (score 2):

How does this look?

http://jsfiddle.net/LukeGT/NxSc3/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    $('#bar').css('position', 'static');
    console.log($('#bar').position().top);
    console.log($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height());

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $('#bar').position().top + $('#bar').height()) {
        $('#bar').css('position', 'fixed');
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#extra').show();
}, 1000);​
```

I simulated the late loading of images by just showing a few extra divs after 1 second.  I believe the problem arises from the fact that the height of the page changes after the code for the bar runs, so it's behaving as it should if the page were shorter (without the images/ajax etc).

What I do instead is position the bar in it's place at the bottom of the page each time the page is scrolled, calculate its height from the top there, and compare this with the scroll height.  If we're too far up, it positions the bar in a fixed position at the base of the page, and otherwise leaves it alone.  It works smoothly in Chrome, but I haven't tested elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a problem with the `$(window).height()` function. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205838/calculating-height-using-jquery-differs-in-firefox-and-chrome). For all the dynamic contents like Images, Video or Ajax-loaded content the height is not added to the result of `$(window).height()` unless it is specified somewhere in the HTML or CSS (and from the referred link I see this happens only in Chrome. You might want to confirm on this though). To those dynamic contents you can either try adding the `height` attribute in html or `height` attribute in the corresponding style.

Comment: It happens on all browser, but mostly on Chrome. We have tried adding a height attribute in html/stylesheet to a fixed content like video. That way the behaviour can be controlled, but I can't apply this on the disqus or other content where I originally don't know its height. What do you suggest?

Comment: Did you try setting the height via Javascript after the page is loaded? I am just guessing it might work.

Comment: We tried it but somehow doesn't get it to work correctly. How do you recommend we should do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but i have found something while inspecting your website...
This is you actual HTML when its working fine as you want..

```
<div class="footer-toolbar-container" id="sticky_for_a_while" style="position: fixed; ">
```

but when it is not working, the `Position` attribute is changing from `Fixed` to `Relative` .

```
<div class="footer-toolbar-container" id="sticky_for_a_while" style="position: relative; ">
```

you can check you script for that or post you script here...

Comment: Yes, exactly this is currently managed by the script, and is required to have the behaviour we needed.  Moreover, you can find the script here: http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/1/

The issue is that it doesn't work when there is any content which is loaded later on or which causes page height to change.

Answer (score 0):

At initial state, your div is in `position: relative` so its offset is based on the container element, not on the total height of the page. The variable `stickyOffset` is set based on that relative offset, that is why it gets clip down sooner than expected while scrolling and also why it works in your JSFiddle as the container there is the page (Iframe) itself.

In your `$(document).ready` function, you'll need to add the offset of not only the footer but also the rest of the offset on top of the containing element so that the offset is based on the total page instead of the containing div.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is required to get the desired behaviour. And the offset is already based on total page height and not containing div.

Comment: Yeah I mixed up `.position()` and `.offset()`, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your example on http://www.sandiegopchelp.com/services/cellphone-repair/htc/ using chrome, I can see that your footer disappears when it gets at the "related links" section. At this moment, you set the position of the footer to "relative" so it will replace it in the regular flow of the document and its position is actually below the "related links" section which is why it disappears off screen (below "related links").

but you calculated the position at which it should become relative on page load only where you should have recalculated it after having added the "related links" section as it changes the page height (I understood that you added afterward, am I right?).

Comment: Yes you're right. It happens only on those section which is added dynamically after the page load. This is built on wp, and the related links section is managed by a plugin.

Comment: Actually the calculation in js works fine if there is no such content which is dynamically loaded after page load.

Comment: this is why I thought you could try recalculating your offset when you add some content to the page. the "sticky_offset" that you calculate in your ready handler is not correct once you add new content : the total page height has changed so the scroll position at which the footer should go to relative positionning changes also.

Comment: actually, the fact that it works sometimes is due to the loading of your additionnal conten( like "related links") being loaded prior to the firing of the ready handler, probably because the network latency was really low this particular time... In these cases, the computed page height is correct because the content has already been added...

Comment: Well, if you do something like $.post(url, function(){..callback code}) to retrieve your data to insert into the page, just complete your callback by adding the footer offset calculation at its end (the code you have in your ready handler). In your case, as you seem to be using a plugin to add the content, you'll have to find a way to add a custom callback or to hook some code into the plugin.

Comment: Exactly, I already tried this earlier. Its actually three plugin that loads content dynamically depending on page requirements.

Comment: well did it work? Or did you try but couldn't hook into the plugins loading functions? Because for me, this is obviously your problem so recalculating your page height after having modified it should fix it...

Comment: We couldn't hook into the plugins loading function.

Comment: Well then I don't really know how you could do. You could just recalculate the page height every 10 seconds using settimeout but it sucks a bit.

Comment: i agree with you. May be that's the problem because few contents are loaded by plugin and inserted into the page dynamically after page has completed loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a zero height div just above the position of the sticky div, which will remain at that position as the page resizes, then check that position as you scroll to determine the position where the sticky div should stop.

Comment: Already tried, this doesn't solves this issue. But helped us to solve one other issue on the same page related to correct positioning of the div. Thanks

Comment: Well, on your linked page, you set the sticky position on page load. i suggest you check it periodically, or check it during the scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it fixed by two techniques, setting explicit height wherever possible using CSS and delaying jQuery function after all images are loaded. Refer this: [Delay some jQuery function until all images are loaded completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863277/delay-some-jquery-function-until-all-images-are-loaded-completely)