# Delay some jQuery function until all images are loaded completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I delay some jQuery / JavaScript function until all the images on a page have finished loading?
Actually, the jQuery function I'm talking about is for setting the offset position for a div. The problem is that the page resizes once the images are loaded completely, so the offset is wrong.

For the jQuery function refer to this question: [Issues with Fixed div on bottom of page that stops at given place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361143/issues-with-fixed-div-on-bottom-of-page-that-stops-at-given-place)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `onload` event which runs after all images or external resources are loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your code here, all images loaded
});
```

You can also use the `load` event for individual images and run your code when they have loaded:

```
$('img.ImageClass').load(function(){
  // The image loaded....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just write the function under a variable like

```
function newfunction(){
//put all the stuff here
}
```

after that call this function on every image load like

```
$('img').load(function(){
newfunction()
})
```

from this the newfunction will call everytime a new image load.