# Javascript bug with .height() in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, coffeescript

I have the following code (coffeescript) that is setting the height of one of my divs dynamically for the content. It works perfectly for Firefox and Safari. I am having problems with chrome. Ive been doing a lot of reading and they say chrome has a bug in the sense that it measures heights from the .height() function differently then other browsers. Is there anyway to fix this or any work arounds anyone has found?

```
resize = ->
  window_height     = $(window).height()

  $('.full-height').each ->
    elm               = $(this)
    wrapper_height    = elm.height()
    difference_height = window_height - wrapper_height
    new_height        = wrapper_height + difference_height
    content_height    = $('#wrapper').height()
    offset            = elm.data('offset-height') || 0

    if(window_height >= content_height)
      elm.css
        height: new_height
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine on Chrome. Where do they say the `.height()` function has a problem?

Comment: It works as in it runs. but chrome is measuring the .height() as too short and causing the content in the div to run out of it. I am not having this problem with any other browser.

Comment: This might be an issue with your styling. For example, if you did `moz-box-sizing` but didn't include `box-sizing` in your CSS, you might have different results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518436/jquery-height-problem-with-chrome