# How to get height of "br" element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I try to get the height of `<br />` on my webpage. I use this snippet.

```
br_size = $('br').height();
console.log(br_size);
```

But only the `Mozilla Firefox` like this code, all other browsers give back 0.
Is there a short JS code that gives me the correct height back?

**PS:** i use this method, because i know that the needed size `X` is `X= other_size - 4*br_size`

Comment: Maybe you should try to calculate the heights with `line-height` css property.

Comment: You should take a look at this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518436/jquery-height-problem-with-chrome)

Comment: I posted answer contain new solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line-break depends on the line-height specified in the HTML/BODY tags, if one isn't specified then the browser will likely use their own. However, if you specify a line-height, say 20px then the line-break should be 20px. You could probably use JavaScript to determine the default line-height

```js
(function() {
  var br = document.getElementById('foo');
  alert(br.scrollHeight);
  if (br.currentStyle) {
    alert(br.currentStyle['lineHeight']);
  } else {
    alert(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(br, null).getPropertyValue('line-height'));
  }
})();
```

```html
<br id="foo" />
```

Comment: works for me, first alert is "0" but the second is allways correct.

Comment: On Chrome 52 second alert is "normal"

Comment: Found a cross-browser solution. Look at my answer.

Comment: @DenisSheremet, if you define something, you can definitely access that, we are talking about default values. ;)

Comment: I guess there is two different ways of solving this: define fake element with same height, or try to parse browser-specific values of `line-height`. Afaik `normal` may have different numeric value between browsers, so the first way is more reliable

Comment: Hah negative votes, well that is an endless discussion, I believe its better to play around OP then getting ddep :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem `<br>` has `height` property. Also you can't see it height in inspect of browser. If there is another elemetn after `<br>`, you can use this code:

```js
var height = $("br").next().position().top - $("br").position().top
console.log(height);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>
<br/>
<p>Goodbye</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ewajLvam/). Works on chrome.

```
var br = $('br').first();
var div = $('<div>Text</div>');

div.css({
  'font-size': br.css('font-size'),
  'line-height': br.css('line-height'),
  'position': 'fixed',
  'visibility': 'hidden',
});

$('body').append(div);

alert(div.outerHeight());

div.remove();
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks Denis.

Answer (score 0):

How about outerHeight?

```
$('br').outerHeight();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6fag6tos/

Comment: Doesn't work ... your outerHeight() shows 2px because you set a border via CSS